# jQuery form clone, how to stop values from being copied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am `adding additional` form on `button` click.

In my form, i have `one drop down`. When `user select value from drop down`, i am `populating other fields value` based drop down selection. You can see in my code i am sending ajax call to retrieve the values before setting them in input field.

**code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var index = 0;
    $("#testButton").click(function() {
      $("#jBuyer").clone().appendTo("#jointBuyer"); 
      index++; 
    });
});
</script>
```

When clone done, `the form fields along with data copied to next form`. 
I don't want it to happen because it is a problem? `How can i stop it?`

With my little knowledge i can understand the problem is with duplicate Name or Id but don't how i can generate them dynamically and then can set their values.

If you interested to know my full code, please see below.

**full code**

```
<div id="jointBuyer" class="JointBuyerDive" style="display:none">
    <div id="jBuyer">
        <div id="inner"class="col-lg-6">
            <form id="buyerForm" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Buyer</label>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Unit No.</label>
                 <select class="form-control" name="junitId" id="junitId" onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="getUnit(this.value);">
                    <option>Please Select Unit No</option>
                    <?php
                       $sql_query= "select * from tble_units";
                       $run_query =mysqli_query($con, $sql_query);
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query )){
                        $unit_no =$row ['unit_no'];         
                        $unit_ID =$row ['unit_ID'];                                                                         
                       ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $unit_ID;?>"><?php echo $unit_no;?></option>
                    <?php }?>
                 </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Type</label>
                 <input type="text" name="unitTypeE" id="unitTypeE" class="form-control" readonly> 
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                 <label>No of Car Parking Purchase</label>
                 <input type="text" name="noOfCarParkingE" id="noOfCarParkingE" class="form-control" readonly>          
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

**Ajax call**

```
function getUnit(value) {
        var dataString = 'id=' + value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getUnitData.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                $('input[name=unitTypeE]').val(obj[0]);
                $('input[name=noOfCarParkingE]').val(obj[1]);
                $('input[name=floorE]').val(obj[2]);
                $('input[name=unitAreaE]').val(obj[3]);
                $('input[name=commentsE]').val(obj[4]);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset form after clone it.

Like this code:

```
var clonedForm = $("#buyerForm").clone();
$("#jBuyer").append(clonedForm);
clonedForm[0].reset();
```

and then you should set unique id to cloned form:

```
clonedForm.attr("id","uniqueId");
```

**append after edit:**

and then in ajax call you should use this code to change only one dropdown:

first change `onchange="getUnit(this)"` and then:

```
function getUnit(obj) {
    var currentForm = obj.parents("form");
    var dataString = 'id=' + obj.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getUnitData.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(result);
            currentForm.find('input[name=unitTypeE]').val(obj[0]);
            currentForm.find('input[name=noOfCarParkingE]').val(obj[1]);
            currentForm.find('input[name=floorE]').val(obj[2]);
            currentForm.find('input[name=unitAreaE]').val(obj[3]);
            currentForm.find('input[name=commentsE]').val(obj[4]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This will part of the problem. After your solution, if i select drop down value in the second form it populates values in the fields of both form 1 and form 2. Why?

Comment: because your selector in "success" section is general. you should specify that. (I edit my answer now)